# Can add but not remove from Azure AD

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

I am able to add users to an Azure AD Security group from a csv, but am having trouble removing them from the Azure AD group (if they're in it) if they ARE NOT in the CSV. This part works just fine.

```
#Connect to Azure AD 
Connect-AzureAD

 #Import the list and save it to a variable
$list = Import-Csv "H:\BPT_Users_Reports\SCJ_BPT_Users_03-07-2024_test.csv"
#Insert the display name of the group here
$group = "BPT User Load Test"

#Retrieve the group name for use later in the script
$GroupObjectID = Get-AzureADGroup -SearchString $group | Select -Property ObjectID

#roll through the list to look up each user and add to the group. 
foreach ($y in $list){
    $y2 = Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId $y.userPrincipalName | Select -Property ObjectID
    $members = Get-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $GroupObjectID.ObjectID -All $true

    if ($y2.ObjectID -in $members.ObjectID) {
    Write-Host $y.userPrincipalName'is already in the Group' -ForegroundColor Blue
    }else{
        Add-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $GroupObjectID.ObjectID -RefObjectId $y2.ObjectId -              InformationAction SilentlyContinue
    Write-Host $y.userPrincipalName'has been added to the Group' -ForegroundColor Green
    }

}

#Disconnect Azure AD
Disconnect-AzureAD
```

Basically, if they no longer meet the requirements to be in the CSV file, I want them removed from the Azure AD group. If tried adding additional FOR EACH statements that if NOT in the CSV then remove from Azure AD group. It goes through the motions, but doesn't remove them.

```
ForEach ($y in $list)
{
       {        
        $UserObj = Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId $y.UPN
        Where-Object {$Group -notcontains $y.UPN}
        Remove-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectID $Group.ObjectID -RfObjectId.ObjectID 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can add but not remove from Azure AD:

Adding member to a group code looks good to me. I modified a little bit of your script to the removal part.

```
foreach ($mem in $members) {
    $existing = $mem.UserPrincipalName
    if ($list.UserPrincipalName -notcontains $existing) {
        Write-Host "removing $existing member from the group"
        Remove-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $GroupObjectID.ObjectID -MemberId $mem.ObjectId
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hey Jahnavi, 

Thanks for cleaning that up a bit. The sytax looks to me to be correct, but I run into the same issue. It goes through the motions, I get no errors in the console, but it only tells me that the members are still in the group. 
I populated the group with the initial test CSV to have 5 users n it. 
Then added the remove for each and removed 2 users from the CSV. 
What I am hoping to have happen is this will add new users who meet the recondition to be in the CSV, and remove them from the Azure AD group if they are not in the CSV,

Comment: The above code works for me. Try running the script with a small set of users for testing purposes to see if the issue persists. @EddieCrandall

Comment: Hi Jahnavi, 
I did. I populated the Azure AD group with 5 users in the CSV. 
Then I removed 2 users from the CSV and ran it again. 
All 5 are still in the Azure AD group and the console tells me that they are all already members. 
Am I missing something in the text?

Comment: Hi Jahnavi, 

I figured it out! Well...you solved this for me. 
In my repeated forehead banging, I apparently forgot to save the CSV.
<insert>epicfacepalm.jpg</insert>